# attempting to create a full page width image with graphix, noindent has no effect

Tags: graphics

I'm just starting to learn TeX and I read that \noindent would allow me to create a full width image that does not include page margins; however, the following code doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth]{universe.jpg}
\end{document}
```

The image appears to be the correct width, but \noindent seems to have no effect.

Comment: You need to start with image on left (right) page border and not at left (right) text border!

Comment: The text block starts at `\oddsidemargin+1in` from the left border of the paper.

Comment: Could someone answer with an example that works?  The comments are informative, but don't lead me to understand how to generate markup that does what I want.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell more precisely what's this for? Often a good solution depends on this kind of information.

Comment: I ultimately want to do something more complicated, but to start learning TeX, I decided to try to make a "meme" postcard with full bleed image and some text overlaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to overlay text on the image. This means the image should go as background image. You can use `background` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
position=current page.center,
angle=0,
color=blue!30,
opacity=0.5,
scale=1,
contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
}%
\begin{document}
  \BgThispage
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add `height=\paperheight` in `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}` too or choose a proper image.

This is possible by `tikz` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.5] at (current page.center)
                          {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Both methods need 2-3 compilations to settle down.

Comment: Thank you!  What does "Both methods need 2-3 compilations to settle down" mean?

Comment: @Ultrasaurus In the first run the coordinates are read and in second the picture is put. You need to compile 2-3 times to get the proper placement of image.

Comment: It seems strange to have a program that requires 2-3 compilations.  Is there another way to write it that addresses that issue?

Comment: @Ultrasaurus: It is the way TeX/LaTeX works. Some instructions are written in aux files in the first run and they are read in second run. With `overlay` optin of `tikz` which is used by `background` package, no other way, you have to compile many times.

Answer (score 2):

> **Update**

For TikZ lovers (I'm one of them), here is a solution which works for any document class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\imageheight

\newcommand{\placeimage}[1]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\coordinate(H);
\node[anchor=north] at(current page.north|-H) {#1};}
\setlength{\imageheight}{\heightof{#1}+\baselineskip}
\vspace{\imageheight}
}
\begin{document}

We can place the image here ...\par
\placeimage{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-A}}\par
and continue our text after the image here ...

\end{document}
```

In this solution, I defined a new macro for placing the image on top of the page at the required position using the commands:

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\coordinate(H);
\node[anchor=north] at(current page.north|-H) {#1};}
```

This will place the image directly below the current position with horizontally centering. Then we need to leave a vertical space equal to the `\imageheight` to continue entering our text. This is achieved by calculating the required space by:

```
\newlength\imageheight
\setlength{\imageheight}{\heightof{#1}+\baselineskip}
```

and adding the calculated space to the last position by `\vspace{\imageheight}`.

> **First Solution**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth]{example-image-A}
}
\end{document}
```

As pointed out by egreg, this can fail in other classes like `book` which has `oneside` or `twoside` setups. So, here is a complete solution which works in all cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,changepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\newcommand{\adjustimg}{% Horizontal adjustment of image
  \checkoddpage%
  \ifoddpage\hspace*{\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\else\hspace*{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\centerimg}[2][width=\textwidth]{% Center an image
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\adjustimg\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\centerimg[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-A}

\newpage

\centerimg[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good for `article` in one side mode. Not for other settings where the text block is not symmetrically placed on the page (in horizontal dimension).

Answer (score 2):

Summing up the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\oddsidemargin-1in
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth]{it} % Name of your graphics here
\end{document}
```

Assumptions: one page document, as we may derive from the comment:

> I decided to try to make a "meme" postcard with full bleed image and some text overlaying it.

[image]

Comment: And what about a real document where one certainly doesn't want to remove the margin?

Comment: @egreg Oh, moving inside `\mbox` for example. But maybe OP wants only one-page document...

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.  I think the answer to my question is that "noindent" just removes and indentation within the margin, but I needed to remove the margin, right?

Comment: @Ultrasaurus Yes. There is standard 1 inch margin around the text. `\oddsidemargin-1in` moves margins on odd sides one inch left.